# image repeats on one page but not on others

Tags: html, css

I've run into a bit of confusion and I'm not sure how to resolve it. 
I have this banner image on a customers website that looks fine on most pages, yet on the contact us page, which should load the top exactly the same, instead loads it as a repeating image which overlaps.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div id="logo"><img id="logo_image" src="http://i.imgur.com/PcRRIN4.png" alt="Gun Dealer Logo" /></div><style type="text/css">.dealer_logo {display:none;} #logo { z-index:-1; position:absolute; top:20px; } #logo_image { margin-left: 100px; height: 100px; }</style>
```

Here's the normal URL where it loads correctly on every page
http://royalpawnandguns.com/
On the contact us page it shows up as an overlapping repeat
http://royalpawnandguns.com/contact.php

I do not have access to the backend, I can only make modifications through an annoying little code box which allows the use of HTML and CSS.
I've tried adding no-repeat to the css, but that doesn't seem to work.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Please add your CSS and simple HTML to this question. Once you fix the issue on the live site, this question becomes useless to future visitors.

Comment: Only US citizens can answer your question :) Please create the minimal code the reflects your issue and post it directly inside your question. Otherwise you're limitign your self and future visitors (once that link goes *off*)

Comment: @Roko, try using a proxy.  Hidemyass seems to work.

Comment: @disinfor, I don't have access to the backend so that code I posted above is exactly what I have put in.  The website is live, I am not the developer, I am only working on it. They give me access to a little UI box...a magic box? to type code into. It only allows HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Squeezit found my proxy: http://jsbin.com/xikene/1/edit?html,css,js,output :D

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I apologize but I hvae no idea what to do with that link :(
I see my code entered into it exactly as I originally wrote it.  Don't see anything about the weird repeating issue.

Comment: @Squeezit look, probably you're new to SO. We're not here to follow links to websites and debug for you. Please see: [ask]. I repeat (since it was not clear from the beginning) Post all the necessary but minimal code to reproduce the issue. Questions (and Answers) should be helpful also for future visitors even once you remove your link or it goes off.

Comment: Also, (tell your boss) blocking IP by country is a terrible idea. An US citizen might be in Europe for business and you'd lose valuable income- I'd go immediately to another website that sells the same crap.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Because I don't know what's causing the issue, I don't know how to duplicate it by posting the necessary code.  If you're unable to follow links then it's perfectly fine, I apologize for posting here.  I'm sure I'll figure it out eventually, it just had me really frustrated so I thought I'd ask for help.

As to the IP blocking, while I don't like it, I guess it has something to do with some laws of some sort. It's for a firearms company.

Comment: @Squeezit learn to use Developer console and how to inspect elements. You'd resolve your issue in a minute.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it's clear you have no intention to help.  I do know how to inspect elements and have been using developer console.  Don't worry about it, I'll figure it out.

Comment: @Squeezit that's why I'm suggestign you to hit F12 on your keabord and inspect the desired element. have you googled how to inspect an element in developer tools? If you ask me, when starting with web-dev - that's the **best suggestion you can get**.

Comment: If you still don't know how, simply **right click** the desired portion of the page you're having issue with and click **"Inspect Element"**. Not hard after all. :) happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contacts page has another element with `id="logo"` in it.

The culprit is here: 
[image: The culprit]

If, as you say, you really have no way of changing the HTML, you could try only targeting the logo in your sidebar, like so:

```
.sidebar_content #logo {
   ...
}
```